# Malformed Policy Error Occurs When Using 2 Separate Policies

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following json files which I am using with Terraform to do the following:

1. Allows the deployment of my Lambda function
2. Allow the creation of a log group when my lambda function invocates.
3. Allow the creation of a log trail named according to the date when the lambda function
   invocates.

The idea is for these log groups / trails to be created AUTOMATICALLY so that I don't have to go into CloudWatch and create a new one every day which would be unproductive.

main.tf:

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "foo"
  secret_key = "foo"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "greet_lambda" {
  filename = "greet_lambda.py.zip"
  function_name = "greet_lambda"
  role = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
  handler = "greet_lambda.lambda_handler"
  depends_on = [aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.lambda_logs]
  runtime = "python3.7"
  environment {
    variables = {greeting = "Hi"}
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "greet_lambda" {
  name = "/aws/lambda/greet_lambda"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_for_lambda" {
  name = "iam_for_lambda"
  assume_role_policy = file("iam_for_lambda.json")
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_logging" {
  name = "lambda_logging"
  path = "/"
  description = "IAM policy for logging from a lambda"
  policy = file("lambda_policy.json")
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_logs" {
  role = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.lambda_logging.arn
  depends_on = [aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda, aws_iam_policy.lambda_logging]
}
```

lambda_policy.json

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:003618259171:log-group:/aws/lambda/greet_lambda:*",
      "Effect": "Allow"
      }
    ]
  }
```

iam_for_lambda:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Sid": "" 
  }
  ]
}
```

Issue:  Everything appears to deploy correctly, however when the lambda function is invoked, a log stream is not automatically created within the log group.

Comment: I've just explained that to your in your deleted question that is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/51279889/2291321. The `assume_role_policy` is the permissions to assume the role and can only contain an assume role policy, not the actions you want the IAM role to perform. Please can you read the answer in that linked question and then revise your question to explain clearly what you don't understand about it?

Comment: I don't see how this previous post is applicable because it doesn't involve applying 2 separate policies to a lambda function.  My question is different in file structure and the objective which I explain is not present in the post you linked.  The question was deleted posted again per the advice of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I also see you downvoted based on lack of effort, however I have made changes to my files in order to mitigate the errors.

Comment: That's not what your Terraform code is doing. You are creating two separate IAM roles and then setting both of their assume role policies to malformed policies that include the IAM actions you want the role to be able to use. It may be worth spending some time reading up on IAM roles and how they are used in AWS.

Comment: I will search for more information regarding IAM roles and report my findings

Comment: The original error has been fixed.  Everything deploys, now the problem is that the log streams don't get created at all.  The lambda function invokes without errors.  I had to create the resource group in the main.tf because that wouldn't become automatically created after lambda invocation.

Comment: Also, specifying the name of one log stream as shown in https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_log_stream.html woudn't meet the objective, unless there was a way to put something like $(date.time) as the log stream name

Comment: turns out there is a timestamp() function in terraform, so I now I need to figure out how to write this pseudo code:   if lambda function gets run, then create logstream with name timestamp()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that I ended up making that worked:

main.tf:

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = ""
  secret_key = ""
  region = ""
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "greet_lambda" {
  filename      = "greet_lambda.py.zip"
  function_name = "greet_lambda"
  role          = "${aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn}"
  handler       = "greet_lambda.lambda_handler"
  depends_on = ["aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.lambda_logs", "aws_cloudwatch_log_group.example"]
  source_code_hash = "${filebase64sha256("greet_lambda.py.zip")}"
  runtime = "python3.7"
  environment {
    variables = {greeting = "Hi"}
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_for_lambda" {
  name = "iam_for_lambda"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}


resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "example" {
  name              = "/aws/lambda/greet_lambda"
  retention_in_days = 14
}


resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_logging" {
  name        = "lambda_logging"
  path        = "/"
  description = "IAM policy for logging from a lambda"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_logs" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.lambda_logging.arn}"
}
```